# Add a button to users.php

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-meta

I am working on a plugin that adds meta data for each user to the users.php table that is displayed by adding columns. I have that done but I would like to also add a button that will delete the meta data of the users when pressed. I'm not sure how I can add it. I would like it to be to the right of the 'change' button. I thought that the behavior would be to reload the page but when it does, I'll have it delete the meta data for each user.

Where would I start to add that button to the page? Is this the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay.. you COULD add a button like you mentioned; but I think this is going to require a lot more code.  The users.php page is using the WP List Table class.. which means we can hook into the `bulk actions` and add our custom value there.

So, let's create a function to add a new value into the bulk actions dropdown box:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_user_del_button');
function my_user_del_button() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id != "users" )   // Only add to users.php page
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('<option>').val('del_user_meta').text('Delete User Meta').appendTo("select[name='action']");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

This will add the "Delete User Meta" value to the bulk actions dropdown box.  Now, we need a function to actually process the data being sent:

```
add_action('load-users.php', 'my_users_page_loaded');
function my_users_page_loaded() {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'del_user_meta') {  // Check if our custom action was selected
        $del_users = $_GET['users'];  // Get array of user id's which were selected for meta deletion
        if ($del_users) {  // If any users were selected
            foreach ($del_users as $del_user) {
            delete_user_meta($del_user, 'YOUR_METADATA_KEY_TO_BE_REMOVED');  // Change this meta key to match the key you would like to delete; or an array of keys.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we iterate through each of the users we placed a checkmark next to.  Then, it will delete the `meta_key` you specified for each of those selected users.

NOTE: You need to change the `YOUR_METADATA_KEY_TO_BE_REMOVED` string to the actual name of the meta_key you would like to delete.  If you are wanting to delete more than a single meta key, you will need to add multiple `delete_user_meta()` functions.

Comment: josh, thanks for the code but I'm getting this error: Notice: Undefined index: users   and it's from this line: $del_users = $_GET['users']; It seems that it does not know what users is. Any suggestion?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work but I notice if someone does not have a user checked, and they attempt to delete some meta data, it will throw an error. I'm guessing that I need to test to see if any users were selected. Do you have any suggestion on testing if $del_users = $_GET['users']; is empty or is there a better way to do it? Thanks again!

Comment: My answer has been edited above (second block).  Sorry about that!

Comment: My pleasure :)  Glad it worked.  Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 3):

Although the JavaScript approach using the `admin_footer` hook what @josh mentions works in most cases. It's definitely not the best approach to add an option to the bulk action dropdown. Because there is a specific hook for that, wooohoee yeah! Try the `bulk_actions-{$screen_id}` filter hook.

```
add_filter('bulk_actions-users', function($actions) {
    $actions['foo'] = __('Foo bar', 'my-namespace');
    return $actions;
});
```

After you got the view ready, it's time to setup the controller for that action. Where we will use the `handle_bulk_actions-{$screen_id}` filter hook.

```
add_filter('handle_bulk_actions-users', function($redirect, $action, $ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        // Perform action for specific id.
    }
    return $redirect;
}, 10, 3);
```

---

*Source: [Custom Bulk Actions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/04/custom-bulk-actions/)*